# Mechanism to draw rear wheel back and tighten chain stuck; oil not helping, what's next?

Tags: maintenance, chain, internally-geared-hub

I have a bicycle with an internally geared hub (Rohloff).  To tension the chain, I loosed the attachment of the rear wheel (dropouts), draw back the rear wheel, and tighten the attachment again.  However, on one side, this mechanism is stuck.  I've oiled it but it's still stuck.  What can I try next?

[image: Tightening mechanism, failing side]

This mechanism is supposed to move back and forth when the bolts are loosened, but it doesn't.  On this photo, I removed the bolts connecting it to the dropout completely, to make sure that isn't the problem.

[image: Tightening mechanism, working side]

Whereas on the other side of my bicycle, it does.

This leaves me with the choice of cycling with a loose chain, or cycling with a slightly less loose chain but a rear wheel that isn't straight.  Not a great choice.  How can I unstuck this mechanism?  I've already tried to oil it.

**Edit:**

The thing on the left (with a thread visible) is stuck.  It is supposed to be connected to the thing sticking out on the right, but regardless of how much I loosed the thing sticking out on the right, the thing on the left won't move.  Sorry, I don't know the right terminology.

Comment: Did you try to soak it in WD40 and then to knock slightly?

Comment: @Klaster_1 I haven't tried knocking too much yet, I'm worried to break things.  My bicycle is currently in a quite useable but suboptimal state...

Comment: What do the threads in the photos do? Is there a nut that runs on them?

Comment: I gather that the cylinder-type thing sticking out the back in the top photo is a female-threaded "nut", and the bottom photo is showing the similar apparatus on the other side that is working OK.  You don't say whether it's the "nut" or the bolt we see sticking out the front that is stuck.  If the bolt is stuck, unthread the nut a few turns and then tap it on the end with a hammer.  If the "nut" is stuck, tap the bolt (as best you can).

Comment: The thing on the left (with a thread visible) is stuck.  It is supposed to be connected to the thing sticking out on the right, but regardless of how much I loosed the thing sticking out on the right, the thing on the left won't move.  Sorry, I don't know the right terminology.

Comment: Screw the thing on the right in at least a half inch from being all the way unscrewed (so that at least a half-inch of threads are engaged), then lightly tap it on the end with a hammer.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Will try

Comment: I'm almost certain that the reason why it's bound up is because the 'thing on the right' pulls on the 'thing on the left' from below (as we see it in the photograph) the axis of the hole (for the axle attachment I presume). This means that there is a tendency for the threaded part to bind up where it passes through the frame – I think a gentle tap down on the 'thing on the right' or prying up gently on the 'thing on the left' would fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little puzzled by the threads that look like they should draw the hub's axle back to tension the chain. They don't appear like they can move, but it also doesn't look like there is a nut on them to pull the axel back. Do you know if they thread into the frame, or are they free to slide?

That said, it appears that the load on the mechanism would tend to misalign the threaded part where it passes through the frame. This is very likely to cause it to jam. I think you could try very gently prying up on the loop where the axle attaches or perhaps tapping down gently on the top of the loop. It shouldn't take much force at all. I'm assuming that the frame is not threaded and that the adjuster should slide freely.

Comment: I second this first paragraph. This is either an optical illusion or that is a bolt with a wing on the end that prevents the bolt from turning more than 1/4 turn.

Answer (score 1):

Try something specifically designed for seized parts. PBlaster or Kroil come to mind. Whatever you do, definitely exhaust the non-mechanical remedies before you get out the breaker bar!